# Break HTML tags and text of a single cell in multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba, split

I am trying to come up with a function that returns each HTML tags and text strings of few selected cells into individual rows of a new Sheet so that I can edit the text rows and then paste everything back to the selected cell.

I have this code, but unfortunately, it is way too basic for my task.

```
Sub SplitCell ()
    Dim txt As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim fullname As Variant

    txt = ActiveCell.Value
    fullname = Split(txt, "<p>; <b>; <i>; </p>; </b>; </i>;")
        For i = 0 To UBound(fullname)
        Cells(1, i + 1).Value = fullname(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Here's a link to a sample worksheet to give you a better idea of what I would like to achieve.

Sample Sheet

[image: Sample Sheet]

Expected result

[image: Expected Result]

Thanks,

Comment: what is happening that isn't right?

Comment: If you're looking for any basic <tag>, you can do a loop from `i = 1 to len()` and when you find the desired split points, take from the last split point to the current i and append it to a pre-dimensioned array.  application.transpose the array back to your sheet (may need to redim array to your max content).

Comment: Hey Nathan, thanks for your answer. Well, my code simply splits the selected cells based on few limited tags, and I need it to function with any HTML tag (so anything between < and >. Also, I want it to actually list those tags in the report sheet, like all the remaining text, an not deleting them, as the function does. I've included a link with a sample file I would like to achieve. Thanks

Comment: @Marrone in few cases will anyone download a link from this site.  Please edit your post to either provide screen shots of data, or excerpts.

Comment: Thanks Cyril, I just edited my post. :)

Answer (score 2):

Would split based on `"<"` not suit your needs, then split on the `">"` of the result, something like so.

```
Sub test()

    Dim s As String
    Dim s1() As String
    Dim v As Variant

    s = "<td>test one</td><b>test two</b>"

    s1 = Split(s, "<")

    For Each v In s1        
        If Len(v) > 0 And Right(v, 1) <> ">" Then        
            Debug.Print Split(v, ">")(1)        
        End If        
    Next v        

End Sub
```

Comment: deleted my answer as this cuts things down to a much simpler use of `split(s,"<")`

Comment: This is only a basic appraoach not sure how it would work on nested, say `<table><tr><td>test</td></tr></table>`